# GallaryView change Images on button Click a

Tags: android, button, image-gallery

Currently I am working with GalleryView and changing images that is working perfectly fine.

But I want to disable swipe of GalleryView and change the loaded images on button click.
How can i achieve this functionality.

My current Class is As Follow

```
public class PopUpWindow extends Activity {
TextView closebtn;
Integer[] pics = {
        R.drawable.account_icon,
        R.drawable.coffee_icon,
        R.drawable.help_icon,
        R.drawable.menu_icon,

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
     setUpDialogProperties();
     this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
     setContentView(R.layout.pop_up_dialog);
     fetchUI();

}
private void fetchUI(){
    closebtn            =           (TextView)findViewById(R.id.okBtn);
    closeDialog();
     Gallery ga = (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.Gallery01);
        ga.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        ga.setUnselectedAlpha(0.0f);
}

private void closeDialog(){
    closebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();

        }
    });
}
private void setUpDialogProperties() {
      requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
      android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow()
        .getAttributes();
      lp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
      getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

     }
 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context ctx;
        int imageBackground;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            ctx = c;
            TypedArray ta = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
            imageBackground = ta.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 1);
            ta.recycle();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return pics.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {

            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {

            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
            ImageView iv = new ImageView(ctx);
            iv.setImageResource(pics[arg0]);
            iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            iv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150,150));
            iv.setBackgroundResource(imageBackground);
            return iv;
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 case R.id.leftButton:
      int position = mGallery.getSelectedItemPosition() - 1;
      if (position < 0)
          return;
      mGallery.setSelection(position);
      break;
  case R.id.rightButton:
      position = mGallery.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1;
      if (position >= mGallery.getCount())
          return;
      mGallery.setSelection(position);
      break;
```

I will setup the onclick for your next and previous button

Comment: how to disable gallery Swipe view in this scenario ?

Comment: you have to override the Gallery's onTouchListener and return always true

Comment: but i m using Base Adapter in this case how to handle that ?

Comment: BaseAdapter and Swipe are not related